# Working on grouped data.tables within a larger data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have recently decided to transform from `data.frame` to `data.table` but I can't seem to succeed in manipulating the `data.table` in the same way.

How would I write the following `ddply` code using `data.table` to accompish the same output

```
# generate the data.table
R> set.seed(42)
R> dt <- data.table(sample = rep(c('a','b','c'),times = 1, each = 5), 
      seq = sample(c('dd','ee','ff'),15,replace=T), 
      num = sample(1:100,15),
      letters = sample(letters,15))

R> dt
     sample seq num letters
 1:      a  ff  95       t
 2:      a  ff  97       u
 3:      a  dd  12       j
 4:      a  ff  47       p
 5:      a  ee  54       a
 6:      b  ee  86       r
 7:      b  ff  14       v
 8:      b  dd  92       d
 9:      b  ee  88       q
10:      b  ff   8       k
11:      c  ee  99       g
12:      c  ff  35       w
13:      c  ff  80       z
14:      c  dd  39       m
15:      c  ee  72       f
```

The code I would use using ddply to have a single line for `sample` and `seq` column containing the `sum(num)` in the new `num` column and `letter` containing the letter with the highest num within each subgroup:
*example: for subgroup `sample == 'a'` and `seq == 'ff'` the letter is `u` because it has `num == 97` because it is higher than 95 and 47*

```
R> df_new <- ddply(dt, .(sample, seq), function(df){
  order_d <- order(df$num, decreasing = TRUE)
  df_new <- df [order_d[1],]
  df_new$num <- sum(df$num)
  return(df_new)
})

R> df_new
   sample seq num letters
1      a  dd  12       j
2      a  ee  54       a
3      a  ff 239       u
4      b  dd  92       d
5      b  ee 174       q
6      b  ff  22       v
7      c  dd  39       m
8      c  ee 171       g
9      c  ff 115       z
```

**How can I do this in a `data.table` way?**

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this: `dt[, sum(num), .(sample, seq)]`

Comment: `dt[order(-num), .(num = sum(num), letters = first(letters)),  keyby = .(sample, seq)]`

Comment: Thank you :) I have edited the question to better explain what I need. I must order the lines within each subgroup by num and take the letter only from the highest value

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg. But in my real data set I have 20 more columns like 'letters'. Do I have to actually write for each first(colname)??? Isn't there a more general way I could modify each grouped data.table seperately like I do for df_new?

Comment: `dt[order(-num), c(num = sum(num), .SD[1L]), .SDcols = !"num", keyby = .(sample, seq)]`

Comment: If @David 's answer works for you, Arik, I guess he would be fine with you self-answering the question. Btw, his code has some optimizations you can read about in `?GForce` if you're interested. Info on these optimizations for a call can be seen by turning verbose on, eg, `dt[order(-num), c(num = sum(num), .SD[1L]), .SDcols = !"num", keyby = .(sample, seq), verbose=TRUE]`